# See also our case processing times?

Tags: terminology

I’m working on translating some email templates for my company, and in those, we refer to our case processing times (on our website).

I originally wrote “read more about our case processing times”, but because we already have a “read more about…” right above it, one of my coworkers suggested I should use “see also our case processing times”. I’m not a native English speaker, but this sounds weird to me.

Is this correct? Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Julie. When you get a moment click on this [**Link**](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and take the TOUR and also click on the HELP button on the right-side of the title bar and check–out the “**help center**”, if you haven’t already done so. There’s a lot to learn about this site, such as how to ask good questions and provide good answers, all about earning "rep" points and the site privileges that come with them. It’s well worth looking around. Anyway, you’re off to a good start. So, have a good time, and we'll see you around (so to speak).

Answer (score 2):

"See also" would probably be better served as a heading for a set of other options after the main article e.g. on Wikipedia on an article about a particular car, you might observe a 'See also:' subheading, followed by a list of similar cars. Given you have multiple fields, if you can change the design, you could add this 'See also' heading (or a 'Read more about' heading) to the top of the section containing all your links. e.g.

> See also/Read more about:
>
> Our Case Processing Times
>
> Our Related Work
>
> etc etc

Alternately, I would opt for just writing the links as purely descriptive of their content 'Our case processing times', 'Our clients', 'Our related work' etc.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use "explore", "learn more" and as pointed out "see also" etc.

Another phrase for "*case processing time*" can be -

You can ***read about*** our **[turnaround time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnaround_time)** for cases.

> - In general, turnaround time means the amount of time taken to fulfill a request. (Wikipedia)